# Criar pasta automaticamente no projeto CSharp com arquivos de audio

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho um projeto em *C#*, criei uma pasta no projeto pelo *Visual Studio 2019* e coloquei 2 *Ogg's* lá. A estrutura é a seguinte:

- App

  - Assets
  - Files (essa é a pasta que coloquei os audios)
  - Model
  - View
  - ViewModel

Tenho uma dúvida, toda vez que compilo para testar a aplicação (CTRL + F5) ela não criar nenhuma pasta no `bin/Debug` do projeto, ou seja, a pasta que criei no projeto não está sendo replicada quando faço a compilação do `Debug`.

Eu sei que consigo criar a pasta na aplicação com o comando abaixo:

```cs
    var path = Application.StartupPath + @"\Files\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
          //Se não existir cria a pasta na raiz do projeto
          Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
```

O problema é que os áudios não vão para a pasta e eles são áudios fixos, não mudam, eu já quero que a aplicação toque esses áudios quando a aplicação abre.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?